# Docker executing a command when running an image

Tags: laravel, docker

I'm using Laravel with docker. Inside my dockerfile I have this command:

```
RUN php artisan config:cache
```

This is useful for production since it cache the configuration. When I'm developing I need to be able to change the configuration quite often, so every time I run the image I need to  execute

```
RUN php artisan config:clear
```

is there a way to run the docker image with a given command? i.e.:

```
docker run my_image "php artisan config:clear"
```

(If you're wondering, I'm doing `docker run` instead of `docker start` quite often since I'm building the image quite often.)
I'd like to avoid using CMD inside dockerfile since it's not really needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run the command inside a currently running container you can use the [exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) command:

`$ docker exec yourapp_web_1 php artisan config:clear`

Comment: I usually create a ./commands folder in my docker set up. I add stuff like this as a bash script that way I can execute it in an easy way. Something like: `./commands/cc.sh`

Comment: Yeah I know, there is no way to run it from the run command? I'm super busy and lazy, I'd like to avoid running two commands if I can run only one.